# Remove duplicate rows from a big table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got data from third party and imported to SQL server. The table has 255,072,636 records and 61,714,772 are unique among these records. The table has neither specific order nor any index. The table has 4 columns: `Field1(float), Field2(varchar(255), Field3(varchar(255), Field4(varchar(255)`. I want to delete the duplicate record based upon `Field1` for which I've run the following query:

```
WITH CTE(Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, DuplicateCount)
AS (SELECT *, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Field1 ORDER BY Field1) AS DuplicateCount
    FROM MyTable)
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE DuplicateCount > 1;
```

but it took 13 hours and then I cancelled it and the above mentioned figures are after that. Is there any better way to remove duplicates?

Comment: What is the reason behind using the same field in partition and order by?

Comment: I don't know but I want uniqueness just in Field1. Like ID-Card Number should be unique and name, father-name, address may be duplicate.

Comment: What do you mean by "records"? A row, a value, a column? What is a unique "record"? A unique row? If so why do you have 200M~ rows where there's any identical to another row? That feels like you have some input and validation issues.

Comment: @Larnu: As I mentioned, I've got the data from third party that is why I'm here.

Comment: That doesn't explain what a "record" is; there is no such thing as a *record* in SQL.

Comment: Record means Row. The previous comment was about `That feels like you have some input and validation issues.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to "Kazi Mohammad Ali Nur" and "eshirvana". I've combine there solutions. At first I created index on `Field1`.

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX Index_Name   
    ON MyTable(Field1);
```

and then I executed following query to insert unique records into a new table and deleted original table.

```
WITH CTE(Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, DuplicateCount)
AS (SELECT *, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Field1 ORDER BY Field1) AS DuplicateCount
    FROM MyTable)
select * into TempTable FROM CTE
WHERE DuplicateCount = 1;
```

and it worked.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of delete you can insert unique rows into a temp table then you can rename that table or copy your desired rows to the original table after truncating that.

Insert unique rows into a table.

```
WITH CTE(Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, DuplicateCount)
AS (SELECT *, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Field1 ORDER BY Field1) AS DuplicateCount
    FROM MyTable)
select * into TempTable FROM CTE
WHERE DuplicateCount = 1;
```

Then either you can rename that table like below:

```
drop table MyTable;
sp_rename 'temptable','MyTable';
```

Or copy unique rows back to the original table:

```
Truncate table MyTable;
insert into MyTable select *from TempTable ;
drop table temptable;
```

Comment: Table name is not important. Can you explain why is insertion batter than delete and what will be the performance difference.

Comment: Though I didn't consider the number of index you have on your table, but since number of rows to delete is almost four times than the number of rows to insert in new table I would go for insert.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

1. make an index on filed1 (this will takes hours)

   ```
   create ix_table on MyTable(files1)
   ```
2. then either delete dups or make a new table for unique values, probably a little bit faster if you just insert into a new table

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4
from 
( select * , 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Field1 ORDER BY Field1) AS dups
  FROM MyTable
) tt
where dups = 1
```

but if you delete from original table , however it would be slower, you already have an index on field1 on that table , if you would need to use that index later on for any query purposes. so in longterm it might be more efficient to keep original table

Answer (score 0):

Just recreate the table:

```
select distinct *
into new_t
from t;
```

I would suggest adding an index on `(field1, field2, field3, field4)` before doing this.

Or for one column uniqueness:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by field1 order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

For this, you want an index on `(field1)`.

If you really need to re-use the name of the original table, either truncate it and re-insert from `new_t` or rename the table.

Comment: Distinct * will compare all fields but I need uniqueness just in field. other field may have duplicates values. Like ID-Card Number should be unique and name, father name may be duplicate.